# ConcurrencyException

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, concurrentmodification, synchronized-block

```
private static HashMap<String, FileInfo> sFileInfoObjectList = new CacheLinkedHashMap<String, FileInfo>();

public static synchronized FileInfo getFileInfoForProvider(...) {
 FileInfo foundFileInfo = null;

 (...)

 foundFileInfo = sFileInfoObjectList.get(hashEntryKey);

 (...)

 sFileInfoObjectList.put(hashEntryKey, foundFileInfo);

 (...)
}

public static synchronized void removeFileInfoForProvider(final int providerId) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Iterator<Entry<String, FileInfo>> it = sFileInfoObjectList.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, FileInfo> pair = it.next();
                FileInfo info = pair.getValue();
                if (providerId == info.mProvider) {                            
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I am getting a ConccurentModificationException in the run() method. I tried following and it did not work:

```
public void run() {
    synchronized(sFileInfoObjectList) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, FileInfo>> it = sFileInfoObjectList.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, FileInfo> pair = it.next();
            FileInfo info = pair.getValue();
            if (providerId == info.mProvider) {                            
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The run() is not in a synchronized block because it is run on another thread.  You could use synchronized in your run method but it would be much simpler to use a concurrent collection which does throw this error. E.g. ConcurrentHashMap.

BTW: I wouldn't start a thread each time as it could be more expensive than just iterating over the collection.  I would use a thread pool, or do it in the current thread.

---

Replace your method with this

```
public static void removeFileInfoForProvider(final int providerId) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            removeFileInfoForProvider0(providerId);
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

static synchronized void removeFileInfoForProvider0(final int providerId) {
    Iterator<Entry<String, FileInfo>> it = sFileInfoObjectList.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, FileInfo> pair = it.next();
        FileInfo info = pair.getValue();
        if (providerId == info.mProvider) {                            
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I am using a LinkedHashMap and the method is synchronized

Comment: The run() method is run in a different thread and it is not synchronized.  The method you have synchronized doesn't touch the collection so it doesn't need to be synchronized.

Comment: You have to lock on the same object which is the class in your case (as the other locks are static) A simpler approach is to have it call a synchronized method on the class.  BTW since your collection is single threaded starting another thread won't help very much.

Comment: I do not know, but all your comments are not self explaining and do not help me

Comment: Since you don't appear to understand any of the instructions given, perhaps you can just replace your code with the above which will work.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it worked. I wrote a test to reproduce the Exception and with your changes the exception does not occur anymore. Anyway I must still analyse carefully why and read more about it to understand it better, but thanks anyways.

Comment: @David You have to think about which object is being locked for which thread.  When you use static synchronized you are locking the class object e.g. `MyClass.class` for the current thread.  Using a different object or starting another thread is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't synchronized `remove()` call for the `Map`. If multiple threads try to call `run()` same time, it will throw `ConcurrentModificationException` which is the reason in your case.

You may need to use either synchronized on run()  (or) use concurrent collection like `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: I assume the OP believes making `removeFileInfoForProvider` synchronized is enough.

Comment: If i synchronize over the collection variable, I do not need to synchronize remove()

Comment: "If i synchronize over the collection variable" do you mean, using Concurrent collection?

Comment: no, see my first post after I wrote: I tried following and it did not work:

Comment: Approach should work fine, but issue could be that you are  synchronizing on the object which is being modified, which may not work. Use some other to maintain synch lock.